# Implement a redirect to Secure to website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

**Implement a redirect to HTTPS to website**

Earlier we have a website with HTTP, and recently we have purchased in to HTTPS. Now I am tried to implement the redirect to HTTPS.

For this I tried below code in

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ## enable rewrites
    
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/$1 [R,L] 
     
    </IfModule>
```

When I uploaded the `.htaccess` file with above code. The website is not able to display.

And my entire `.htaccess` file as below.

```
    #DirectoryIndex index.html

#AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
#RemoveHandler .html .htm
#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
#RewriteRule ^/?inscription/map\.html$ - [F,L]

<FilesMatch "\.html$" >
    #ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

#Canonicalization  issue
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Google Caching Issue
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/$1 [R,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

#Redirect from http to https 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^ www.example.com/ [L,R=301]


ErrorDocument 404 www.example.com     
 
 
</IfModule> 

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>


<Files "phpinfo.php">
     
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

#<Files >

#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

#</Files>

Options -Indexes
```

Can you please help on this. to implement the redirection from http to https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with below code.

```
#Force from http to https 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Note that this check against `%{ENV:HTTPS}` (an `HTTPS` "environment" variable, as opposed to the `HTTPS` _server_ variable) is non-standard and implies your host has implemented some kind of front-end proxy. However, this answer fails to address the other fundamental issues (missing _scheme_ on absolute URLs - as addressed in my answer) which would have also resulted in redirect loops / malformed redirects before it even got to the HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
> ```

You need to include the scheme, ie. `https` in the *substitution string*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The same applies to all the other redirects in your `.htaccess` file.

If you don't explicitly include the HTTPS scheme in a HTTP to HTTPS redirect then it's never going to redirect to HTTPS. However, a relative path *substitution* (ie. one that does not start with a scheme or slash) is seen as relative to the current directory (unless `RewriteBase` is defined). So, a substitution string like `www.example.com` will effectively be treated as a subdirectory from the current directory (document root) and attempting to convert this into an external redirect will result in a malformed redirect like `http://www.example.com/path/to/public_html/www.example.com/<foo>`.

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 www.example.com
> ```

You have a similar issue with your `ErrorDocument` directive. However, you should not be "redirecting" to the custom error document (which is what will happen if you specify an absolute URL here). You should define a custom error document. eg. `/errors/my404.html` and state this in the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/my404.html
```

The custom error document is then served using an internal subrequest. There is no "external redirect" here.

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> Can you please edit above `.htaccess` file and post here?

I've removed all the commented-out code sections - so add those back as appropriate. Although several of the mod_rewrite sections that were commented out I assume are just earlier/incorrect attempts. I've also reordered some bits (eg. it is more logical to define `Options` and `ErrorDocument` directives early in the file - you certainly shouldn't split these up). I've omitted the mod_expires and mod_deflate sections for brevity.

I've also updated the deprecated mod_access_compat (`Order`, `Deny`, etc.) directives for Apache 2.4 `Require all denied`.

I'm also assuming the www subdomain is canonical and you have no other subdomains.

```
# Allow FollowSymlinks (required for mod_rewrite)
# and prevent directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

# Define custom error documents
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/my404.html     

# Block access to specific files
<Files "phpinfo.php">
    Require all denied     
</Files>

# Enable mod_rewrite rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On 

# Canonical redirect: non-www to www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Canonical redirect: HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# mod_expires directives go here...

# mod_deflate directives go here...
```

Clear your browser cache before testing and test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Note I assume you have already tested the `SERVER_PORT 80` check and this works as intended on your server<sup>***1**</sup>. I notice in your commented-out code you are also checking the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header - this is only required if your application server is behind a front-end proxy that manages the HTTPS connection. If this is the case then checking `SERVER_PORT` (or `HTTPS`) may fail.

---

<sup>***1**</sup> **UPDATE#2:** It seems this is not the case and you are having to implement a non-standard check for `%{ENV:HTTPS}` instead of checking the `SERVER_PORT`, which is resulting in a redirect loop. This implies that your webhost (a *shared* hosting platform I assume) is using some kind of front-end proxy to manage the SSL connection and your application server is actually communicating over plain HTTP to the front-end proxy.

```
# Force from http to https 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you please edit above `.htaccess` file and post here?

Comment: The website unable to load `This page isn't working example.com redirected you too many times.`

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the HTTP to HTTPS redirect loop (as you've stated above). The other issues in your `.htaccess` file - which I've addressed above - would have also caused a redirect loop. But without additional information there was nothing to suggest that checking `SERVER_PORT 80` was an issue - since this is reasonably "standard" (so I had naturally assumed this had been established as the correct check for your server/host). Please upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exact what difference between. Your **Update#2** worked for me. Thank you